# Angular Failed ng build --prod

Tags: javascript, angular

I got error when

> ng build --prod

my MEAN Stack App. On my console return :

> ERROR in : Unexpected value 'FlashMessageModule in
>   C:/mean/angular/node_modules/angular-flash-message/dist/flash-message.module.d.ts'
>   imported by the module 'AppModule in
>   C:/mean/angular/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule
>   annotation.

This is my flash-message.module.d.ts file :

```
export declare class FlashMessageModule {
}
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the NgModule annotation to declare it as a module to Angular:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({})
export declare class FlashMessageModule {
}
```

Comment: Edited as your suggestion, but it give me ERROR in : Unexpected module 'FlashMessageModule in C:/mean/angular/node_modules/angular-flash-message/dist/flash-message.module.d.ts' declared by the module 'AppModule in C:/mean/angular/src/app/app.module.ts'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.